# Sliding hidden sections of a JPanel into view

Tags: java, swing, jframe, visible

I want to display a JFrame ( made with the Netbeans GUI Editor ) that has an enclosed panel ( the panel encovers the entire JFrame ). The panel is twice as wide as the frame, so I want it so that when a button is pressed inside of the panel, the panel's visible area slides over ( over about 2 seconds) to the hidden area of the JPanel and the previously visible section of the JPanel becomes invisible. I couldn't find any function how to set the currently visible section of a JPanel, so the function and/or a different solution to this would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you put the JPanel in a JScrollPane, one that if you wish does not show its scrollbars. Then you could easily use the scrollpane's model and a Swing Timer to create an animation that shows the JPanel sliding.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions is CardLayout based http://java-sl.com/tip_slider.html

You can add 2 (or more) panels into container and rotate them.